# Clarification of external interface vs source interface filter in Fortigate DNAT/VIP

Tags: nat, fortigate, dnat

On a Fortigate firewall, one can configure Destination NAT using the *DNAT & Virtual IPs* section of the GUI, or the `config firewall vip` section of the CLI.

When you create a DNAT object using either method, you must define the object's *Interface* (`extintf`), and can optionally define its *Source Interface Filter* (`srcintf-filter`).  The *Interface* can be set to a single interface name (or the value `any`), while the *Source Interface Filter* can be set to zero, one or more interface names.

https://community.fortinet.com/t5/FortiGate/Technical-Tip-Firewall-VIP-difference-in-srcintf-filter-and/ta-p/259694 is intended to describe the difference between these two settings, but I am having trouble reasoning about what it is saying.  One statement that article makes is:

> `extintf` will not bind the VIP to the specific interface. That means that the VIP shown as an example above *[a sample with `extintf = wan1` and no `srcintf-filter`]* will accept connections from each and every interface.

**So what is `extintf` *actually* defining?**  (I am fairly certain it is *not* the interface on which to expect the target/real device -- that is determined by routing.)

Can anyone with experience with these devices clarify what the difference is in a practical sense?  In particular, what changes in the translation/forwarding logic and/or policy requirements in the following hypothetical scenarios:

1. `extintf` and `srcintf-filter` set to the same single value, `ifA`
2. `extintf` set to `ifA` and `srcintf-filter` set to `ifB`
3. `extintf` set to `ifA` and `srcintf-filter` set to multi-value `ifB ifC`
4. `extintf` set to `ifA` and `srcintf-filter` set to multi-value `ifA ifB ifC`
5. `extintf` set tp `any`

...?

---

For a more-tangible example, I have a lab Fortigate with `wan` and `lan` interfaces.  Two VLANs are defined on the `lan` interface, creating `vlanA` and `vlanB` interfaces.  Two IPSec VPNs tunnel between the `wan` interface and two external devices, creating `vpnA` and `vpnB` interfaces.

The tunnels establish correctly and the Fortigate recieves packets from the remote subnets (verified by packet-capture).  The Fortigate's local encryption domain for both tunnels is 192.0.2.0/28, but this is not a real subnet in either *vlanA* or *vlanB*.

I have a DNAT object `dnatA` which is *intended* to direct a remote user coming in via *vpnA* and requesting 192.0.2.1 to a device with a real location on *vlanA*.  I have a second DNAT object `dnatB` which is similarly intended to direct a remote user requesting 192.0.2.1 via *vpnB* to a real device on *vlanB*.

This works exactly as intended, when I use the following settings:

1. *dnatA* having `extintf = vpnA` and `srcintf-filter = vpnA` (i.e. matching values)
2. *dnatB* having `extintf = vpnB` and `srcintf-filter = vpnB` (i.e. matching values)
3. A Policy entry permitting communication between `srcintf vpnA` and `dstintf vlanA`
4. A Policy entry permitting communication between `srcintf vpnB` and `dstintf vlanB`

It does *not* appear to work with:

1. *dnatA* having `extintf = any` and `srcintf-filter = vpnA`
2. *dnatB* having `extintf = any` and `srcintf-filter = vpnB`
   (why is `vpnA` not considered one of `any`?)

Nor does it appear to work with:

1. *dnatA* having `extintf = vlanA` and `srcintf-filter = vpnA`
2. *dnatB* having `extintf = vlanB` and `srcintf-filter = vpnB`
   (why not, if "`extintf` will not bind the VIP to the specific interface"?)

*If* I were to subsequently require users of new remote tunnel `vpnA2` to also access the device in *vlanA*, I might consider naiively consider adding `vpnA2` to the `srcintf-filter` of *dnatA* (since `srcintf-filter` can accept multiple values).  However, **what then is the correct logical value for `extintf`?**

Given my example scenario sees nothing forwarding when `extintf` value is *not* the same as the `srcintf-filter` value, **what is a viable reason for having mismatching `extinf`/`srcintf-filter` values?**

*(Lab device is currently on FortiOS 7.0, but I don't* think *the version is the deciding factor here...)*